# Why does the reported Pico W clock speed differ from its datasheet?

Tags: system-clock

- Datasheet: Up to 133mhz
- print(str(machine.freq())) = 125000000 (hz, presumably)

Comment: 125 MHz fits the criteria of up to 133 MHz.

Answer (score 3):

Have you read the [various pico datasheets](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/raspberry-pi-pico.html#documentation)? If not, you should familiarize yourself with those. A micro*controller* like the Pico is a different animal than a micro*computer* like the Raspberry Pis. You will need to need to be a bit more *hardware-oriented* when dealing with a microcontroller.

The system clock speed is determined by several factors. *The frequency of the crystal oscillator is the primary determinant*, but not the only one. The external oscillator used for the Pico W (Y1) appears to be a nominal 12 MHz unit (p/n ABLS-12.000MHZ-B4-T) with a 30 ppm tolerance. Variances from the oscillator's specified *load capacitance* will further increase its frequency variance, as will the stability of the *phase-locked loops* (PLLs) that are used to step up the oscillator frequency to reach the system clock frequency.

There's a decent, brief description of some of the factors that influence the oscillator (and therefore the system clock) frequency in [Section 2.3 of this RPi document](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/hardware-design-with-rp2040.pdf). For further details, you can find many resources online ([for example](https://www.edn.com/oscillators-how-to-generate-a-precise-clock-source/)). It's a relatively deep topic; there are entire books devoted to it if you're that keen on the details.

[image: crystal oscillator source]

As you've recognized in your question, the specifications for the RP2040 chip (and therefore your Pico W board) indicate a ***maximum*** system clock frequency of 133 MHz. They *also* specify the `"RP2040 supports 1MHz to 15MHz crystals"`. Consequently, one would expect the maximum system clock frequency of 133 MHz to be reached with the 15 MHz crystal. Since the Pico W board uses a 12 MHz crystal, it seems reasonable its *nominal* system clock frequency will be less than the maximum. Note this is **not** a precisely linear relationship, but in general the value of the system clock frequency will increase with increasing external input frequencies.

Finally, if you feel that 125 MHz is not sufficient, the RPi documentation suggests at least two alternatives for increasing it: replace your current Y1 component with a 15 MHz unit, or replace it with a CMOS clock source whose output is a 3.3V square wave.

Comment: Answer is shaping up to me as: Depends on its crystal which can vary.  The datasheet I read mentioned in my question is where I got the 133mhz.  You mention overclocking, I don't require it.  Note if you underclock yours by half, expect it to freeze and have to flash_nuke.uf2 it to bring it back like I had to.  This new world is exciting, a static shock can give out +2 thousand volts of electricity, allegedly.  Too bad we only retain 80% what we read at most.  I'll leave this question running a bit more in case anyone else wants to weigh in.

Comment: @Flood: It seems you have got the gist of it. FWIW, I did not mention `overclocking`; I don't know that term is applicable on a microcontroller. Leave it open as long as you like - that's up to you.

Comment: Crystal circuits are analog not digital hence they are subject to time and temperature drift along with original frequency error. Also there is capacitance that will change with time and temperature. To get a better understanding of this try this link: "https://www.testworld.com/wp-content/uploads/understanding-frequency-accuracy-in-crystal-controlled-instruments.pdf" I have instruments that have the crystal in an oven and require about 12 hours to stablize.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The current draft (2.1) of the referenced section (2.3) of the referenced datasheet (hardware design with rp2040) does not specify a 15mhz xtal for 133mhz clk_sys.  More significantly, I and many others are able to run the RP2040 at 133mhz from a 12mhz crystal.  I have confirmed this by hand with a frequency counter!  The asker simply does not need a 15mhz crystal.  OTOH it may be that a more accurate 12mhz crystal would help? Possibly the RP204 is throttling itself during the clock-testing process at boot. That could be an iffy clock, iffy power, something else?

Comment: @MykleHansen: ... or simply an iffy comment?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer for the Pico SDK: the SDK boots to 125mhz for historical reasons.  Try calling set_sys_clock_khz() to set it to 133mhz after boot.

Long version:
Section 2.18.2 of the RP2040 datasheet explains how the RP2040 uses a PLL (phased locked loop) to generate a 133mhz clk_sys (the main system clock) from a 12mhz crystal, and a second PLL to generate the 48mhz clock for USB.

The clock speed is NOT just linearly related to the crystal speed. There is a PLL that generates a higher frequency (such as 133mhz) from a lower one (such as 12mhz), and that PLL must be configured with a set of four values: a frequency multiplier (FBDIV), two frequency divisors (POSTDIV1 & POSTDIV2) and the crystal speed (FREF).  The datasheet section referenced above goes into more details about the ranges for those values, and what kind of power/speed/accuracy tradeoffs can be had by tweaking them.

It's actually kind of hairy to calculate it by hand. Thankfully, the datasheet provides a Python script to calculate useable values for you, given your crystal speed and desired frequencies.

Also, some of the various runtimes available for RP2040 manage this complexity for you. For instance I use an Arduino Pico runtime that automatically sets my clk_sys speed at 133mhz, presuming (correctly in my case) that I have a 12mhz crystal.  OTOH, the RP2040 SDK defaults to a 125mhz system clock, using the settings described in datasheet section 2.18.3.  (I think this is for historical reasons; they wrote the SDK using earlier versions of the chip that were a little slower.)

So the real answer is dependent on the runtime you're using, and of course your crystal speed.  If you're bare-metal programming it, then your code is probably calling pll_init() somewhere during boot with some set of parameters; in that case, try the Python script above and see if you can get some better values for those parameters and the crystal you have.

But if you're using the Pico SDK, the documentation suggests you can simply adjust the system clock on the fly after boot, by calling set_sys_clock_khz().  I have not tried this; please report back if you do.